# Could not publish a .NET application using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-publish

I created a .NET Framework 4.8 solution for more than 5 years now. I have always published it to Azure platform. For the last 2 weeks, I have tried to publish it from Visual Studio Community, 2022 to Azure platform but unable to complete the process. I could not Create Web App from the visual studio but was able to create the Web App from the web account and downloaded the Publishing Profile. With the publishing Profile, I could not create dependencies from the visual studio because the publishing window disappeared each time along the way and requested me to login into my account. Every effort to login did not work. Please is this a new issue or a bug in the visual studio? Any contributions will be appreciated. I have never had any issues publishing until now.Tried creating SQL database from the web account but Visual Studio's publishing window could not discover the dependencies.

Below image is what I am getting: